# how to count occurrence of hashtag (e.g: #lol) in string - php

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to know if it is possible to count the occurrences of hashtags in a file, for example if I had a file with randomly entered hashtags like:

> wow, that film was #hilarious
>
> I #love turtles
>
> #YouTube has funny videos that I #love <3

Is it  possible to get an array with the following `["hilarious":1,"love":2,"youtube":1]`

PS: the key is the content of the hashtag, and the value is the amount of times it was found. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: `preg_match_all('/#(\w+)\b/', $string, $matches);
var_dump(array_count_values($matches[1]));` or use `preg_match_all('/#(([\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+))\b/', $string, $matches);` for a unicode compliant version that also supports numbers within the hashtags

Comment: @MarkBaker it does not seem to work, when tested my myself

Comment: [Works well enough](https://3v4l.org/45h0a)

Comment: @MarkBaker, oh - thanks. I have no idea why is wasn't working when I tested it. Thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker, sorry - but just to check, is there any way of preventing it from getting the #hashtag if there is an `&` before it (example: `&#33` = not wanted, but `#33` = is wanted). Is that possible as I am not the best with regularexpressions

Comment: `preg_match_all('/[^&]#(([\p{Pc}\p{N}\p{L}\p{Mn}]+))\b/', $string, $matches);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use to count the number of hashtags with words

> ### preg_match_all

Here is a working example for you to understand.

```
$string = 'count of #0, #hello, #hello, #1 #2';   
preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $string, $occurrence);
$array = $occurrence[1];
$vals = array_count_values($array);
print_r($vals);
```

> ### output
>
> ```
>  Array 
>  (
>   [#0] => 1
>   [#hello] => 2
>   [#1] => 1
>   [#2] => 1
>   )
> ```